# How to get a value from CV_8UC4 matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I successfully create and fill a matrix with depth and RGB data from the Kinect V2 libfreenect2 library like so:

```
cv::Mat(registered.height, registered.width, CV_8UC4, registered.data).copyTo(cpu_depth);
cv::imshow("depth", cpu_depth);
```

I believe this matrix is equivilent to [X,Y,Z,R,G,B,A] for each point within the image. How do I access the unsigned char values within the matrix?

I have tried like this:

```
uchar xValue = cpu_depth.at(cv::Point(20, 20))[0];
```

but it doesn't compile and I feel I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: `cv::Vec4b pixel = cpu_depth.at<cv::Vec4b>(cv::Point(x, y));` now you can access the 4 unsigned char values (which means 8UC4) of that pixel by `pixel[0]`, `pixel[1]`, etc. Vec4b is just a simple array with 4 unsigned char values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to state that you have 4 bytes per chanel with a cast. So to correctly access points within the matrix you do this:

```
uchar xValue = cpu_depth.at<cv::Vec4b>(cv::Point(20, 20))[0];
```

Comment: If someone could explain to me why this is happening i'd gladly accept an explained answer...

Comment: You can access like `cpu_depth.at(...)` or `cpu_depth(...)` only if you defined the matrix like `Mat4b`. Since you declared it as `CV_8UC4`, you need `at<type>`, where the type is a `Vec4b`, a vector of 4 uchar. If you need to access the first, simply do `[0]`. It's exactly the same as any other type in OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

This matrix is NOT equivalent to [X,Y,Z,R,G,B,A] for each point. This matrix is 2-dimensional array of `cv::Vec4b` elements (i. e. `cv::Vec<uchar, 4>` elements - one `uchar` element per channel). Each element can be `(R, G, B, A)` or `(x, y, z, val)` or something else - it's just 4 values at position `(x, y)`.

Thus for access element in position `(x, y)` for desired `channel` you can use the following options:

- `cpu_depth.at<cv::Vec4b>(cv::Point(x, y))[channel]` - get channel value at point `(x, y)`;
- `cpu_depth.at<cv::Vec4b>(y, x)[channel]` - get `channel` value at point `(x, y)` - matrix first index is row, that's why firstly `y` and then `x`;
- `*(cpu_depth.ptr<uchar>(y) + 4 * x + channel)` - value of pointer in `y`-th row and `x`-th column, i. e. at position `(x, y)`.